# iOS simulators are showing up in xamarin.forms project Visual studio 2022

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, ios-simulator, xcode14.3

I recently updated my Xcode version to 14.3, which comes with iOS SDK version 16.4. However, I noticed that after the update, my iOS simulators are no longer showing up in Visual Studio. In the previous version (14.1), they were visible. My deployment target version is set to 15.0, and I have already tried uninstalling and reinstalling Xcode, but the issue persists. I also installed version 14.2 of Xcode, and the simulators were visible in the IDE. It seems to be a problem with the latest version of Xcode. Has anyone else updated to the latest version and experienced similar issues? Please let me know. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a known issue with XCode 14.3. Here is an unreleased version of  Xamarin iOS that fixed this problem:
https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/17561